# HTML Select Drop Down on iPhone4

Tags: html, select, iphone-4

I am trying to get a simple HTML Select/option drop down box to work on an iPhone 4.  Currently, when the user clicks (taps) the drop down box, nothing happens. 
I searched the net for hours now and cannot find a solution that does not involve iScroll or jquery or something.  And even those did not seem to really work. I even contacted Apple but that didn’t go anywhere either.

Here’s the simple HTML.  For those who don’t know off the top of their heads, ‘dir’ refers to reading direction which I used to get the styling I needed.  At this point I am not too concerned about style, I just want the drop down box to drop down.

```
<select id="joint_dia_us" class="select"  dir="ltr"  name="joint_dia_us" >
      <option value="select">Select</option>
      <option value="4.5" >4.5"</option>
      <option value="4.75">4.75"</option> 
 </select>
```

A JavaScript solution is fine if that’s what is required. I am sure this has come up many times for many people but there does not seem to be a straight forward answer out there.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you not getting the standard ios select control? It works for me.

Comment: No.  When the user clicks (taps) the select drop down on an iPhone4 nothing happens.  Works on android and iPhone5.  Could dir=”ltr” be a problem? (BTW, ios stands for iPhone operating system?)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there was a conflict with other JavaScript on the page which was disabling some default actions. When the JavaScript is removed the drop downs work as expected.